# KQL Kusto Query multiple tables using same variable

Tags: kql

Regarding the Kusto Query Language for advanced hunting on Defender ATP

I'm looking to query the information for one computer but across multiple tables

I use the Let command to assign the computer name to a variable and this works but only for the 1st table,  in this case DeviceNetworkInfo

The results only include the 1st object DeviceNetworkInfo there is no result for the other 2
I'm looking to get the results from all tables using the single hostname variable.

So no results for lines 2 and 3. I only want to type the hostname once.

What i'm using is below

Thanks

```
0  Let hostname = "Computer1";
1  DeviceNetworkInfo   | where DeviceName contains hostname;
2  DeviceProcessEvents | where DeviceName contains hostname;
3  DeviceAlertEvents   | where DeviceName contains hostname;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should work as is. Make sure the other two tables have relevant data.

P.S. I think in your case you can use `has` instead of `contains`, as it's much more performant (see more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/datatypes-string-operators)).

Comment: I've queried the other tables individually and they all contain data but when I run the query for multiple tables and export to a csv only table from the 1st line is exported.

Comment: Can you try to run the query in Kusto Explorer, without exporting to a csv? This way we'll know if the query doesn't work correctly, or there's a bug in the "export to csv" functionality.

Comment: Yep tried that examined the output within the window but same only 1st line is outputted.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this:

```
let host = "computername";
search in (DeviceNetworkInfo, DeviceProcessEvents, 
AlertInfo) 
// put in timestamp 
DeviceName =~ host
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).